# What is the deep mean besides Apache Math Mean?, see code

Tags: java, apache

Analyzing the code of Mean

```
public double evaluate(final double[] values,final int begin, final int length) {
    if (test(values, begin, length)) {
        Sum sum = new Sum();
        double sampleSize = length;

        // Compute initial estimate using definitional formula
        double xbar = sum.evaluate(values, begin, length) / sampleSize;

        // Compute correction factor in second pass
        double correction = 0;
        for (int i = begin; i < begin + length; i++) {
            correction += values[i] - xbar;
        }
        return xbar + (correction/sampleSize);
    }
    return Double.NaN;
}
```

I don't understand the point of second pass through array.

If `n = length`, and sum is sum of all elements, then

```
xbar = sum/n
correction = sum - n*xbar // literally, all values - n times of xbar
and then returned value is
sum/n + (sum - sum) / n = sum/n
```

So why do they do this second pass?

Or it's just the trick to avoid any double calculation mistakes?

Comment: Yes, almost certainly to deal with floating-point issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is an implementation of 
[Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)
or something similar